# Calculate column value based on previous row and the same calculated column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am struggling with calculating `Calc` based on `Val1` and `Val2`.

`Calc` = `previous_row.Calc` + `previousr_row.Val1` - `previous_row.Val2`

Input data are ordered by `Date`.

Expected output:

```
+---------+--------+------------+------+
|  Val1   |  Val2  |    Date    | Calc |
+---------+--------+------------+------+
| 0,00    | 0,00   | 2016-01-01 |    0 |
| 1000,00 | 0,00   | 2020-01-01 |    0 |
| 0,00    | 0,00   | 2020-01-15 | 1000 |
| 0,00    | 500,00 | 2020-02-01 | 1000 |
| 0,00    | 300,00 | 2020-03-01 |  500 |
| 0,00    | 0,00   | 2020-03-15 |  200 |
| 0,00    | 200,00 | 2020-04-01 |  200 |
+---------+--------+------------+------+
```

Tried LAG function already, successfully getting data from previous row, but I was not able to get Calc calculated value from the previous:

`LAG(Val1) OVER (ORDER By Date) - LAG(Val2) OVER (ORDER BY Date)`

In real world scenario I will add PARTITION BY, but that is different story. Would like to keep it simple for now.

UPDATE:
Inspired by others:

`SUM(Val1) OVER(ORDER BY Data) - SUM(Val2) OVER(ORDER BY Data) - Val1 + Val2 AS Calc`

While it calculates proper values, is this efficient?

I am using latest SQL Server 2019 / Azure SQL.

Comment: Please post your attempt. It sounds like you were closer than you thought you were.

Comment: I have updated my question. Also, inspired by @Gordon Linoff, provided my version with question if this is effective solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for cumulative sum functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(val1) over (order by date) - sum(val2) over (order by date)
from t;
```

Comment: Not exactly the answer, but has inspired me to find one. I have updated my question with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ALTER FUNCTION calc (@lagDate DATE)
    RETURNS INT
    AS
    BEGIN
        IF @lagDate IS NULL
            RETURN 0

        DECLARE @r INT

        SELECT @r = isnull(lag(val1) OVER ( ORDER BY [date] ), 0) - 
                    isnull(lag(val2) OVER ( ORDER BY [date] ), 0) + 
                    dbo.calc(lag([date]) OVER ( ORDER BY [date] ))
        FROM dbo.ss
        WHERE [date] <= @lagDate

        RETURN @r
    END
    GO

  SELECT *
        ,dbo.calc([date]) calc
    FROM dbo.ss
```

Comment: Seems to work, however I have found simpler solution. Thank you.

Comment: could you tell me your solution?

Comment: You will find it in my post within "UPDATE"